# How to get mid point of triangle in opegl

Tags: opengl, game-physics

i have code of triangle drawing on plane which are follow

```
              glTranslatef(0,0,-6);


        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);        
            glVertex3f( 0.2, 0.0, 0.0 );        
            glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.2, 0.0 );        
            glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.2 );        
          glEnd();
```

If i m right triangle is drawing from point (0,0,-6). I want to calculate the middle point and vertices of triangle ( more and less like radius or diameter of circle). Is it right angle triangle ?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with OpenGL (it's simple math).

Lot's of formulas (depending on the kind of "middle point" you're refering to) can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center).

Using your current coordinates/vertices it's actually an equilateral triangle (all sides have the same length, each angle is 60 ° on the inside).